# MySQL\Maria DB?

Tags: mysql, linux

I have newly installed Centos 7.2 installed on server and i learn that it comes with MariaDB. When i ran command 
mysql --version 
i got following result "mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1".

when i tried mysql -u root
it gives me access denied error message.

So my understanding is that i don't have to install MySQL as it comes with it. how i can access.

I am not Linux\MySQL guy & I need help on that. Doing so is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Regards
Jay

Comment: There are so many resources out there to deal with this problem.  Have you read [this Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) question?

Comment: Yes, i read it and its not helping.  when i type mysql -u root, i am getting following error. "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"     Thanks

Comment: I disagree.  I think it does help.

Comment: when i did mysqld --skip-grant-tables i got following error.            [root@server /]# mysqld --skip-grant-tables
160721 20:17:02 [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!

160721 20:17:02 [ERROR] Aborting

160721 20:17:02 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Comment: First type `sudo su` from the console, which will switch you to the root Linux user.  Then try your steps again.

Comment: didn't helped after running sudo su

Comment: getting same error after doing sudo su

Comment: I followed this link but still not able to go thru. https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-and-configure-mariadb/

Answer (score 1):

A Problem could be that the service is not actually running yet
You can check if the service running with the command below:

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
```